# Java network client-server (file sneding), stuck in client receive loop

Tags: java, file, networking, send

i tried to make  a simple client-server (with some gui) the server sends the data and the client receive it (the save of the file works too) but the client seems to be stucked in the receive-loop.
I started both threads with ".start()". 
I have marked the position of the problem with bold style.

My some of you have a idea why the programm in the client dont goes on... - best wishes ghali

Server:

```
public class Server extends Thread implements Runnable{

    public File choosenfile;
    public int port = 42001;
    public boolean running = true;
    public String myAdress = "localhost";
    public ServerSocket serverSocket;
    public BufferedInputStream bis;
    public boolean debug = true;

    public OutputStream os;


    public void run() {


        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        while(running){

            Socket socket = null;


            try {
                System.out.println("Listening on port: "+port);
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            /*
             * Dies ist die stelle an der man einen Thread aufmachen kann
             */


            // 1. File-Hülle anlegen dazu muss man deren größere wissen
            if(debug) System.out.println("Server: 1.");



            int count;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            try {

                os = socket.getOutputStream();

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            BufferedInputStream in = null;

            try {

                in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(choosenfile));

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                    while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                         os.write(buffer, 0, count);
                         os.flush();
                    }

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


             if(debug) System.out.println("Server: finish sending");

              try {
                os.flush();
                 if(debug) System.out.println("Server: close");
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            running =false;
        }

    }

}
```

Client:

```
public class Client extends Thread implements Runnable{
    public Gui gui; //graphical surface
    public boolean running = true;
    public boolean debug =true;

    //Networkstuff

    Socket socket;
    DataInputStream is;
    public byte[] returnFile;

    public Client(Gui gui){
        this.gui = gui;

    }

    public void run() {


        try {
            socket = new               Socket(InetAddress.getByName(gui.inetAdress),gui.portServer);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }


        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(gui.path);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int count;
        InputStream in = null;

        try {

            in = socket.getInputStream();
            int i =0;

        }
        catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        }


            try {
                while((count=in.read(buffer)) >0){
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, count);

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        **//folloing functions are not executed anymore and i dont know why**
        gui.loadPicture();



        try {
            fos.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple. `read()` blocks until

- data is available in the stream, or
- the stream is closed

The server sends bytes to the stream, but never closes it, so the client reading from this stream doesn't have any way to know if some more data will come or not, so it blocks.

Close the stream at server-side, or design a protocol allowing the client to know when to stop reading (like for example sending the number of bytes in the file, then sending these bytes).

Comment: According to the code, the server should be closing the stream, but the client's just not detecting it

Comment: I don't see any call to `os.close()` or to `socket.close()` at server-side.

Comment: Doesn't closing ServerSocket also close it's Sockets?

Comment: The javadoc doesn't say it does, and your experiment shows that it doesn't.

Comment: Then, it sounds like this is probably your answer. Try it and let us know

Comment: You can add a shutdown call on the socket: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#shutdownOutput()